# How to pass value from one function to another in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want return a value of videoController from this function and pass it like a parameter to another. When I print value inside this function I get value as I expect but when pass it to another and print it I get null.

```
Future<VideoPlayerController> _startVideoPlayer() async {
VideoPlayerController vController =
    VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoFile.path));
videoPlayerListener = () {
  if (videoController != null && videoController.value.size != null) {
    // Refreshing the state to update video player with the correct ratio.
    if (mounted) setState(() {});
    videoController.removeListener(videoPlayerListener);
  }
};
vController.addListener(videoPlayerListener);
await vController.setLooping(true);
await vController.initialize();
await videoController?.dispose();
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    imageFile = null;
    videoController = vController;
  });
}

await vController.play();
return videoController;
```

}

Comment: Consider a State Management solution like Provider or RiverPod.  Definitely simplifies getting the data around and notifying on change to trigger rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Future<VideoPlayerController> _startVideoPlayer() async {
    VideoPlayerController vController =
    VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoFile.path));
    videoPlayerListener = () {
        if (videoController != null && videoController.value.size != null) {
          // Refreshing the state to update video player with the correct ratio.
          if (mounted) setState(() {});
           videoController.removeListener(videoPlayerListener);
    }
    return videoPlayerListener;
   };
 vController.addListener((){_startVideoPlayer();});
      await vController.setLooping(true);
       await vController.initialize();
      await videoController?.dispose();
 if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
            imageFile = null;
             videoController = vController;
             });
          }

       await vController.play();
       return videoController;
```

Comment: I got error The argument type 'VideoPlayerController' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.